# mysql, select coalesce overhead

Tags: mysql

What would be the MySql overhead if using COALESCE on every SELECT column since I'm tired to get DBNUll errors in my VB app. Should I be worried about?

```
Select COALESCE(price_small_breed, 0), COALESCE(discount_small_breed, '') From tblServicePrice Where service_id = .... just some example found on net
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you should not be worried about the overhead.

The only performance issue that I know of with `coalesce()` is in some versions of *SQL Server* (not MySQL!), where the first argument gets evaluated twice when it is not NULL.  This is a problem when it is expensive, such as a subquery.

However, in general, the overhead for a built-in function will be minimal compared to the cost of moving data in and out of the database.

There is an exception in more complex queries, where use of a function such as `coalesce()` can prevent an index being used for some operations.  Once again, this doesn't apply in your case.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps the best solution would be to update the schema so that the fields won't allow null values. You can turn off null, and set a default value (e.g. 0 or '') to solve the problem.

Comment: This is how is actually implemented (I tried to avoid NULLs) but when some LEFT JOIN don't find specified index, the returned result will contain NULLs... So as much as I want to escape them, they keep sneak into my app :)